# How to overcome this error and save file to excel when i have datetime in one of my column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, export-to-excel

I have a dataset of players where the score of their each match is given. Every player gets scored in each match on the basis of performance. I have to make a column called 'recentperformance' next to every player in each match and that should contain the score/performace in the most recent match

I have grouped the data according to matches and its various players for the match but i dont not sure how to search for each player in every group of match and get their score from the most recently concluded match.

'''

```
  for name, group in df.groupby('matchid'): 
     for  row_index, row in group.iterrows():
          col = row['player']
```

'''
 I don't exactly know how to proceed, can anyone please help?

DATA
'''

```
   matchid   player   dateandtime                       score 

   51526        gwen   2012-01-09T16:51:00.000-05:00       67
   51678527     lara   2012-01-09T16:51:00.000-05:00       45
   51526        lara   2012-01-101T16:51:00.000-05:00      89
   51678527     gwen   2012-01-101T6:51:00.000-05:00       96
```

''''
EXPECTED

```
   matchid   player   dateandtime                       score  recntprformnce   

   51526       gwen   2012-01-09T16:51:00.000-05:00       67     Nan
   51526       lara   2012-01-091T16:51:00.000-05:00      89     Nan
   51678527    lara   2012-01-101T16:51:00.000-05:00      45     89
   51678527    gwen   2012-01-101T6:51:00.000-05:00       96     67


    ................................................
```

if player has never participated in any contest before then display Nan( recentperformance shortened the column name to fit in a line)

Comment: what should the recent performance be if a player did not participate in match 526 but did participate in match 525?

Comment: the recent performance should be based on the most recent concluded test so it should take into account datetime and put the recent performance from it into 527 if the player participated in that also matchid is not in ascending or anything. the most important is date

Comment: the matchid is for grouping only!

Comment: if you can please drop any suggestions on how this should be done or anything else.